# Consecutive Remote Rsync Commands (Purpose Defeated by Multiple Password Prompts)

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, rsync

I have two huge folders that I want to rsync **one after the other** using one command.

Command 1:

```
rsync --compress /home/user/folder/  user@192.168.1.10:/home/user/a/folder
```

Command 2:

```
rsync --compress /home/user/folder2/  user@192.168.1.10:/home/user/b/folder2
```

Combined in One Command:

```
rsync --compress /home/user/folder/  user@192.168.1.10:/home/user/a/folder ; rsync --compress /home/user/b/folder2/  user@192.168.1.10:/home/user/folder2
```

After entering this command, I am prompted for the password for the remote server. That's fine. However, after the first command completes, I am again prompted for the same credentials (while I'm not around); therefore defeating my purpose of combining the commands.

I'd like to (1) perform one command, (2) leave, and (3) come back later to see that both jobs were completed **one after the other**.

Is this possible without scripting?

**Edited:** I modified my example to reflect that the destinations are not within the same parent folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
rsync --compress /home/user/folder2 /home/user/folder user@192.168.1.10:/home/user/
```

it will do what you want.

The one you wrote with the semi-column just concatenates the two commands. It is normal that it asks the password.

Or if you really want to rsync it one after another than you can use ssh with key to avoid passwords asking.

Comment: The ssh key suggestion is an acceptable workaround, but the command you suggested only works when the two destinations are within the same folder. However, to be fair, my question didn't properly emphasize the scenario I intended.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you can't use an ssh key? That would the the normal approach to solving the password prompt issue (followed by `expect` if a key is not possible).

I hope you're running this in a protected session, using something like `screen` or `tmux`.

Comment: Yeah, as Stone also recommended, ssh keys do indeed overcome the inability to achieve this with a command.

Comment: Its a shame that the credentials provided (initially) don't authenticate the second statement (given that the joined commands are all entered at once).

Comment: Oh, and why are screen or tmux necessary versus "terminal" (in Ubuntu)?